# disabling cpu throttling for all CPUs and cores, installing ATLAS

Tags: cpu, benchmarking, cpufreq

I'm installing ATLAS on a multicore system. It runs Rocks OS, a linux distro specialized for cluster computing. I need to turn CPU throttling off.

According to a guide at [csrc.tamu-commerce.edu](http://csrc.tamu-commerce.edu/projs/rocksadmin/wiki/RocksClusterBenchmarks), "$ /usr/bin/cpufreq-selector -g performance" turns off throttling on one CPU, but not all of them. They provide a way to turn off others, but does this control each CPU, or each individual core?

Comment: Note: I may have posted this in the wrong place, wasn't entirely sure.

Comment: Do you have more than one CPU? It should work for all cores and all cpus... Unless you have a Xeon or Opteron or something you probably only have a single physical CPU.

Comment: I asked my professor who said, "I can't remember how many CPUs there are. It's at least a 2 quad cores in each machine." I looked in /sys/devices/system/cpu/ which has a directory for cpu0 through cpu15, so I'm assuming each core is considered a CPU. Would that be farfetched?

Comment: Yeah, each core is considered to be a separate processor, and often if hyperthreading is enabled, then you'll get twice the processors (hyper-threading turns one physical core into two virtual cores).  You're probably using a Nehelem or Westmere Xeon processor.

Comment: Check in /proc/cpuinfo as well, but there probably are 16 processors listed there as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through the cores and set the governor for each.

```
CORES=$(cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/possible | tr '-' ' ')
for CPU in $(seq $CORES); do
    /usr/bin/cpufreq-selector -g performance -c $CPU
done
```

A good place for this code would be `/etc/rc.local`.

Comment: I haven't tried this for two reasons. First, I found out that someone else has already turned throttling off for all the CPUs. Second, I have limited time. I do want to see if this will work later on though.